# installing R Markdown- cannot knit to PDF, LaTeX error

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, rtools, tinytex

I am trying to knit an R Markdown in a new install. First, in RStudio I went to File > New File > R Markdown and created one with PDF output format. That resulted in an Error in the render tab:

```
Error: LaTeX failed to compile R-Markdown-sample.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips
```

I went through the troubleshooting steps there and installed the rtools and markdown packages. I tried to install the tinytex packages, but then I get a curl error:

```
Error in curlGetHeaders("https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet") : 
  libcurl error code 28:
    Failed to connect to mirror.ctan.org port 443 after 21047 ms: Timed out
```

Comment: Are you able to access https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet?

Comment: @YihuiXie Yes, I am.

Comment: That's odd. Perhaps it's just a temporary problem? I have pushed [a fix](https://github.com/rstudio/tinytex/commit/840cf5fc8fb070433f7d1993e168de30e439881d) in **tinytex**. You may `remotes::install_github('rstudio/tinytex")` and retry.

Comment: Do you get the same Network timeout if you tried again today? This specific one is a Network Timeout. I assume `tinytex::install_tinytex()` won't work, but can you try this command in there R terminal.